# Unknown Ethereum folder on my C drive

Tags: blockchain

I have an `Ethereum folder` which weights `2.5GB` in this path:

```
C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming
```

which has two folders in it:

> geth
>   [image]
>
> keystore
>   [image]

Do i need 'em ? It's not going to broke my instalation of ethereum on my comp ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the files created when you start syncing a `geth` node. The first folder holds the history of the blockchain that you have downloaded so far.

The file in the second folder is your keystore file. This is your encrypted private key. Additional accounts that you create will appear there as well.

Comment: So it’s not the configuration folders etc right ? I can just delete them

Comment: It is  ETH, not ETC (the folder would be called Ethereum Classic if it was ETC). And you should keep your keystore file (UTC--...) if it has any funds in it. The rest is your node data and you can always redownload that if you want, so yes, you can delete it.